# Getting time that is between constraints

Tags: c#

I have these 3 strings (using # as a delimiter):

```
Name#startTime#endTime#room

Meeting#19:00:00#20:30:00#Conference
Hist 2368#19:00:00#20:30:00#Large Conference Room
Hist 2368#09:00:00#10:30:00#Large Conference Room
```

I want to know how would I generate this

```
Conference             9:00:00 19:00:00
Large Conference Room  10:30:00 20:30:00
Large Conference Room  20:30:00 22:00:00
```

So what this is generating are the times of a room that are free. In the top 3 strings we can see that Conference is occupied from 19:00:00 to 20:30:00 so the free time is 9:00:00 to 19:00:00 (A day starts at 9:00:00 and ends at 22:00:00).

Comment: are you familiar with the string.Split Method.. also what does the exact string look like are you reading this from a file or is it one long value in a text file for example `Name#startTime#endTime#room#Meeting#19:00:00#20:30:00#Conference#Hist 2368#19:00:00#20:30:00#Large Conference Room#Hist 2368#09:00:00#10:30:00#Large Conference Room` if so looks like you are missing some `#` delim between Conference, Hist Conference Room, and Hist if you have any code please show it

Comment: These are 3 separate strings there are no `#` between  Conference, Hist Conference Room, and Hist. As for the code there is not much to show.

Comment: I will post a simple example that you can mess around with use the debugger to see how the DataTable is filled with the split data based on your `#` delimiter

Comment: since you are reading 3 separate strings look at the `string.Split()` you really need to get familiar with this if you are going to be splitting files based on a delimiter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to make this task relatively easy you need to define a class that understands how to split a period of time given a potentially overlapping period of time.

Here's that class:

```
    private sealed class Period : IEquatable<Period>
    {
        public DateTime StartTime { get; private set; }
        public DateTime EndTime { get; private set; }

        public Period(DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime)
        {
            this.StartTime = startTime;
            this.EndTime = endTime;
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (obj is Period)
                return Equals((Period)obj);
            return false;
        }

        public bool Equals(Period obj)
        {
            if (obj == null)
                return false;
            if (!EqualityComparer<DateTime>.Default.Equals(
                        this.StartTime, obj.StartTime))
                return false;
            if (!EqualityComparer<DateTime>.Default.Equals(
                        this.EndTime, obj.EndTime))
                return false;
            return true;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            int hash = 0;
            hash ^= EqualityComparer<DateTime>.Default
                .GetHashCode(this.StartTime);
            hash ^= EqualityComparer<DateTime>.Default
                .GetHashCode(this.EndTime);
            return hash;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return String.Format("{{ StartTime = {0}, EndTime = {1} }}",
                this.StartTime, this.EndTime);
        }

        public IEnumerable<Period> Split(Period period)
        {
            if (period.StartTime <= this.StartTime)
            {
                if (period.EndTime <= this.StartTime)
                    yield return this;
                else if (period.EndTime >= this.EndTime)
                    yield break;
                else
                    yield return new Period(period.EndTime, this.EndTime);
            }
            else if (period.StartTime < this.EndTime)
            {
                yield return new Period(this.StartTime, period.StartTime);
                if (period.EndTime < this.EndTime)
                {

                    yield return new Period(period.EndTime, this.EndTime);
                }
            }
            else
                yield return this;
        }
    }
```

The important code here is the `IEnumerable<Period> Split(Period period)` method. It goes through each possible case when comparing two time periods and returns zero, one or two periods that can be left after the split.

So, given your input data is like this:

```
var lines = new []
{
    "Meeting#19:00:00#20:30:00#Conference",
    "Hist 2368#19:00:00#20:30:00#Large Conference Room",
    "Hist 2368#09:00:00#10:30:00#Large Conference Room",
};

var full_day =
    new Period(
        DateTime.Parse("09:00"),
        DateTime.Parse("22:00"));
```

I can then run this code to determine the free times:

```
var free_times =
    from line in lines
    let parts = line.Split('#')
    let Start = DateTime.Parse(parts[1])
    let End = DateTime.Parse(parts[2])
    orderby Start, End
    group new Period(Start, End) by parts[3] into groups
    select new
    {
        Room = groups.Key,
        FreePeriods =
            groups.Aggregate(new [] { full_day },
                (ys, x) => ys.SelectMany(y => y.Split(x)).ToArray()),
    };
```

The result I get is:

[image: result]

NB: Your example results in the question do not match your data. I have assumed that your data is correct and ignored your example results.

Comment: how do i run this? when I print out the results I get `{ Room = Large Conference Room, FreePeriods = GCWE_Scheduler.Period[] }
{ Room = Conference, FreePeriods = GCWE_Scheduler.Period[] }`

Comment: How would i print out the freeperoids array? i am using this to print: `foreach (var s in free_times) {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }`

Comment: It sounds like you are running it just fine, but you're then trying to do a `.ToString()` to get the values out. That's just not always a good way to do it. Just remember that `FreePeriods` is an array and just access the elements like you normally would.

Comment: `Period` is just a class that has a start time and an end time and it knows how to split against another period. It's doing the heavy logic of taking a period of time and removing chucks of time from it.

Comment: `int counter = 0;
            foreach (var s in free_times) {
                Console.WriteLine(s.Room);
                Console.WriteLine(s.FreePeriods[counter]);
                counter++;
            }` It only shows one row for each.

Comment: Of course it does. You're not iterating over each `FreePeriod`. Try this instead: `foreach (var s in free_times) { Console.WriteLine(s.Room); foreach (var fp in s.FreePeriods) { Console.WriteLine(fp); } }`