# Count hours between datetimes with flexible day time range

Tags: c#, algorithm, datetime

I'm searching for some elegant algorithm to count hours over multiple days with a predefined "work-hour-day-range".

A real world example is: Count only the working hours of a rented object.

The DataTime range can begin inside or outside the defined "work-hour-day-range".

**Example**

I created a little example with 5 different scenarios. Hopes this makes it more clear.

- Row 1    = Date
- Row 2    = Day-Time-Hours
- Row 3-7  = 5 different date ranges to count the hours for

[image: Time table with 5 example time spans]
[larger image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8s1Ta.jpg)

The only way comes to my mind is a for loop over every day inside the range and multiple, complex if-the trees inside. But I hope somebody is smarter than me and can give me a little hint for some faster and elegant way.

Thanks many time for your help! :)

**UPDATE 1**

Based on Lashanes answere I implemented it this way...

```
public struct DateSpan
{
    public DateTime begin, end;

    public DateSpan(DateTime begin, DateTime end)
    {
        if (begin > end || end < begin)
            throw new Exception("Not possible");

        this.begin = begin;
        this.end = end;
    }

    public DateTime Begin
    {
        get
        {
            return this.begin;
        }
    }

    public DateTime End
    {
        get
        {
            return this.end;
        }
    }

    public TimeSpan TimeSpan
    {
        get
        {
            return this.End - this.Begin;
        }
    }

    public TimeSpan GetWorkTimeSpan(TimeSpan? workTimeBegin, TimeSpan? workTimeEnd)
    {
        if (this.Begin.Date == this.End.Date)
        {
            long totalWorkTimeTicks = Math.Min(workTimeEnd.Value.Ticks, this.End.Ticks) - Math.Max(workTimeBegin.Value.Ticks, this.Begin.Ticks);

            return TimeSpan.FromTicks(totalWorkTimeTicks);
        }
        else
        {
            TimeSpan dailyWorkTime = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
            dailyWorkTime -= workTimeBegin ?? TimeSpan.Zero;
            dailyWorkTime -= TimeSpan.FromDays(1) - workTimeEnd ?? TimeSpan.FromDays(1);

            long totalDaysWorkTimeTicks = (int)(this.TimeSpan.TotalDays) * dailyWorkTime.Ticks;

            long firstDayWorkTimeTicks = Math.Min(dailyWorkTime.Ticks, Math.Max(0, workTimeEnd.Value.Ticks - this.Begin.TimeOfDay.Ticks));

            long lastDayWorkTimeTicks = Math.Min(dailyWorkTime.Ticks, Math.Max(0, this.End.TimeOfDay.Ticks - workTimeBegin.Value.Ticks));

            return TimeSpan.FromTicks(firstDayWorkTimeTicks + totalDaysWorkTimeTicks + lastDayWorkTimeTicks);
        }
    }
}
```

and the test cases...

```
 DateSpan dateRange1 = new DateSpan(new DateTime(2012, 01, 01, 07, 00, 00), new DateTime(2012, 01, 03, 15, 00, 00));
 DateSpan dateRange2 = new DateSpan(new DateTime(2012, 01, 01, 02, 00, 00), new DateTime(2012, 01, 03, 20, 00, 00));
 DateSpan dateRange3 = new DateSpan(new DateTime(2012, 01, 01, 04, 00, 00), new DateTime(2012, 01, 03, 23, 00, 00));
 DateSpan dateRange4 = new DateSpan(new DateTime(2012, 01, 01, 23, 00, 00), new DateTime(2012, 01, 03, 09, 00, 00));
 DateSpan dateRange5 = new DateSpan(new DateTime(2012, 01, 02, 12, 00, 00), new DateTime(2012, 01, 02, 20, 00, 00));

 Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("dateRange1: {0}", dateRange1.GetWorkTimeSpan(new TimeSpan(04, 00, 00), new TimeSpan(17, 00 ,00)).TotalHours));
 Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("dateRange2: {0}", dateRange2.GetWorkTimeSpan(new TimeSpan(04, 00, 00), new TimeSpan(17, 00, 00)).TotalHours));
 Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("dateRange3: {0}", dateRange3.GetWorkTimeSpan(new TimeSpan(04, 00, 00), new TimeSpan(17, 00, 00)).TotalHours));
 Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("dateRange4: {0}", dateRange4.GetWorkTimeSpan(new TimeSpan(04, 00, 00), new TimeSpan(17, 00, 00)).TotalHours));
 Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("dateRange5: {0}", dateRange5.GetWorkTimeSpan(new TimeSpan(04, 00, 00), new TimeSpan(17, 00, 00)).TotalHours));
```

Result is..

```
dateRange1: 47 // should be 37h
dateRange2: 52 // should be 42h
dateRange3: 52 // should be 42h
dateRange4: 18 // should be 20h
dateRange5: -17628067  // should be 6h
```

What did I do wrong? I think I understand the way Lashane explained but don't see my error... :(

Comment: The question isn't terribly clear to me. Could you please provide simple example using concrete data (preferably compilable)?

Comment: I try to make the example more precise, but I can't provide some code because this is what I try to get help for. ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

algorithm could be quite simple, I assume that all date ranges are rounded to hours, ie no minutes/seconds

so, to calculate number of working hours you need:

1. Number of whole days between date times, like `int totalDaysHours = 14 * (int)((dtTwo - dtOne).TotalDays);` note that we're rounding down to get only full days
2. Working hours in first day, like `int firstDayHours = Math.Min(14, Math.Max(0, 18-dtOne.Hour));`
3. Working hours in last day, like `int lastDayHours = Math.Min(14, Math.Max(0, dtTwo.Hour - 3));`

NOTE - if start and end dates are the same you need to go another branch:

`int totalWorkingHours = Math.min(18, dtTwo.Hour) - Math.max(4, dtOne.Hour);`

Constants here:

- **14** - number of working hours per day
- **18** - first non working hour in day after work time
- **3** - last non working hour in day before work time

Notes about min/max:

1. max with 0 changes all negative values to 0, but keeps positive ones, for example: last day we've finished at 2 (ie 0 working hours), so Math.Max(0, 2-3==-1) = 0
2. min needed to limit number of working hours to 14 per day, for example: last day we've finished 20, Math.min(14, 20-3==17) will give us 14 only

here is working implementation based on your code:

```
    if (this.Begin.Date == this.End.Date)
    {
        long totalWorkTimeHours = Math.Min(workTimeEnd.Hours+1, this.End.Hour) - Math.Max(workTimeBegin.Hours, this.Begin.Hour); // note + 1

        return TimeSpan.FromHours(totalWorkTimeHours);
    }
    else
    {
        TimeSpan dailyWorkTime = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
        dailyWorkTime -= workTimeBegin;
        dailyWorkTime -= TimeSpan.FromDays(1) - workTimeEnd;

        long totalDaysWorkTimeHours = ((long)this.TimeSpan.TotalDays - 1) * (dailyWorkTime.Hours + 1); // note -1 for days (3rd January - 1st January = 1 whole day, not 2, +1 for hours

        long firstDayWorkTimeHours = Math.Min(dailyWorkTime.Hours + 1, Math.Max(0, workTimeEnd.Hours + 1 - this.Begin.Hour)); // +1 hours

        long lastDayWorkTimeHours = Math.Min(dailyWorkTime.Hours + 1, Math.Max(0, this.End.Hour + 1 - workTimeBegin.Hours)); // +1 hours

        return TimeSpan.FromHours(firstDayWorkTimeHours + totalDaysWorkTimeHours + lastDayWorkTimeHours);
    }
```

why do we need to add 1 to hours, because passed argument is 17 (which is last working hour, and if start time is 17 too - we should get 1 as result), the same for dailyWorkTime, 17-4 give us 13, but actually we have 14 working hours

also noticed small problem:

```
    public TimeSpan TimeSpan
    {
        get
        {
            return this.End.Date - this.Begin.Date; // use dates instead of original time stamps
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Lashane, thanks for your answere I made another answer based on your answer. Can you look at it seems not to work proper. :(

Comment: @SteffenMangold you have standard off by one mistake

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a class for a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26965334/259769) that defined a `Period` class that was used to work out free periods of time. I've extended that class to solve this problem.

First up, here's the input data:

```
var periods = new []
{
    new Period(new DateTime(2014, 1, 1, 7, 0, 0), new DateTime(2014, 1, 3, 16, 0, 0)),
    new Period(new DateTime(2014, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0), new DateTime(2014, 1, 3, 21, 0, 0)),
    new Period(new DateTime(2014, 1, 1, 4, 0, 0), new DateTime(2014, 1, 4, 0, 0, 0)),
    new Period(new DateTime(2014, 1, 1, 23, 0, 0), new DateTime(2014, 1, 3, 10, 0, 0)),
    new Period(new DateTime(2014, 1, 2, 12, 0, 0), new DateTime(2014, 1, 2, 21, 0, 0)),
};
```

Here's the query I wrote to calculate the hours during working periods:

```
var query =
    from period in periods
    let workingPeriods =
        Enumerable
            .Range(0, period.EndTime.Date.Subtract(period.StartTime.Date).Days + 1)
            .Select(n => period.StartTime.Date.AddDays((double)n))
            .Select(d => new Period(d.AddHours(4.0), d.AddHours(18)))
    let remainders = period.Remove(workingPeriods)
    let hoursDuringWorkingPeriods = period.TotalHours - remainders.Sum(x => x.TotalHours)
    select new { Period = period.ToString(), hoursDuringWorkingPeriods };
```

That gave me this result:

[image: result]

This is the updated `Period` class:

```
private sealed class Period : IEquatable<Period>
{
    public DateTime StartTime { get; private set; }
    public DateTime EndTime { get; private set; }

    public Period(DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime)
    {
        this.StartTime = startTime;
        this.EndTime = endTime;
    }

    public double TotalHours
    {
        get
        {
            return this.EndTime.Subtract(this.StartTime).TotalHours;
        }
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is Period)
            return Equals((Period)obj);
        return false;
    }

    public bool Equals(Period obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (!EqualityComparer<DateTime>.Default.Equals(
                    this.StartTime, obj.StartTime))
            return false;
        if (!EqualityComparer<DateTime>.Default.Equals(
                    this.EndTime, obj.EndTime))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int hash = 0;
        hash ^= EqualityComparer<DateTime>.Default
            .GetHashCode(this.StartTime);
        hash ^= EqualityComparer<DateTime>.Default
            .GetHashCode(this.EndTime);
        return hash;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("{{ StartTime = {0}, EndTime = {1} }}",
            this.StartTime, this.EndTime);
    }

    public IEnumerable<Period> Remove(Period period)
    {
        if (period.StartTime <= this.StartTime)
        {
            if (period.EndTime <= this.StartTime)
                yield return this;
            else if (period.EndTime >= this.EndTime)
                yield break;
            else
                yield return new Period(period.EndTime, this.EndTime);
        }
        else if (period.StartTime < this.EndTime)
        {
            yield return new Period(this.StartTime, period.StartTime);
            if (period.EndTime < this.EndTime)
            {

                yield return new Period(period.EndTime, this.EndTime);
            }
        }
        else
            yield return this;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Period> Remove(IEnumerable<Period> periods)
    {
        return Remove(new [] { this }, periods);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<Period> Remove(IEnumerable<Period> selfs, IEnumerable<Period> periods)
    {
        if (periods == null || periods.IsEmpty())
        {
            return Enumerable.Empty<Period>();
        }
        else
        {
            var period = periods.First();
            var nexts =
                from s in selfs
                from ss in s.Remove(period)
                select ss;
            return periods.Skip(1).Any() ? Remove(nexts, periods.Skip(1)) : nexts;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Good solution with linq. But I think it has a much slower performace.

Comment: @SteffenMangold - Seriously? Performance is an issue? This is all happening in memory. Unless you're dealing with hundreds of thousands of records this should be quite fast. Re-use and maintainability should be king.

Comment: this is exact what I'm doing, sorry. I have to proof hundreds of thousands of records from a solar energy plant, so performance is an important fact to me. To be exact at this moment there are 49.540.066 records.

Comment: @SteffenMangold - Fair enough. That's a lot of records. Nevertheless, I just did a test and processed 49,540,066 records - it took less than 7 minutes to process. I suspect that if you're running a batch process, pulling the records from a DB, with the memory overhead,etc, that 7 minutes would be a small fraction of the overall processing time. I doubt performance of this code would be a big factor.

Comment: I understand you, but 1. I don't say your answer is wrong 2. I can only mark one answer here as "Solution". So I voted for the faster on. I'm sorry...

Comment: @SteffenMangold - I have no trouble with you choosing a different answer. I only was concerned that saying my solution has "much slower performance" was just a bit misleading in practical terms.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Lashanes answere I changed the code to return a precise TimeStamp value...

## Code

```
public struct DateSpan
{
    public DateTime Begin
    {
        get
        {
            return this.begin;
        }
    }

    public DateTime End
    {
        get
        {
            return this.end;
        }
    }

    public TimeSpan TimeSpan
    {
        get
        {
            return this.End - this.Begin;
        }
    }

    public TimeSpan GetWorkTimeSpan(TimeSpan? workTimeBegin, TimeSpan? workTimeEnd)
    {
        if (this.Begin.Date == this.End.Date)
        {
            long totalWorkTimeTicks = Math.Min(workTimeEnd.Value.Ticks, this.End.TimeOfDay.Ticks) - Math.Max(workTimeBegin.Value.Ticks, this.Begin.TimeOfDay.Ticks);

            return TimeSpan.FromTicks(totalWorkTimeTicks);
        }
        else
        {
            TimeSpan daySpan = this.End.Date - this.Begin.Date;

            TimeSpan dailyWorkTime = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
            dailyWorkTime -= workTimeBegin ?? TimeSpan.Zero;
            dailyWorkTime -= TimeSpan.FromDays(1) - workTimeEnd ?? TimeSpan.FromDays(1);



            long totalDaysWorkTimeTicks = (int)(daySpan.TotalDays - 1) * dailyWorkTime.Ticks;

            long firstDayWorkTimeTicks = Math.Min(dailyWorkTime.Ticks, Math.Max(0, (workTimeEnd ?? TimeSpan.FromDays(1)).Ticks - this.Begin.TimeOfDay.Ticks));

            long lastDayWorkTimeTicks = Math.Min(dailyWorkTime.Ticks, Math.Max(0, this.End.TimeOfDay.Ticks - (workTimeBegin ?? TimeSpan.Zero).Ticks));

            return TimeSpan.FromTicks(firstDayWorkTimeTicks + totalDaysWorkTimeTicks + lastDayWorkTimeTicks);
        }
    }
}
```

## Test Case

```
 TimeSpan workTimeBegin = new TimeSpan(04, 00, 00);
 TimeSpan workTimeEnd = new TimeSpan(18, 00, 00);

 DateSpan dateRange1 = new DateSpan(new DateTime(2012, 01, 01, 07, 00, 00), new DateTime(2012, 01, 03, 15, 00, 00));
 DateSpan dateRange2 = new DateSpan(new DateTime(2012, 01, 01, 02, 00, 00), new DateTime(2012, 01, 03, 20, 00, 00));
 DateSpan dateRange3 = new DateSpan(new DateTime(2012, 01, 01, 04, 00, 00), new DateTime(2012, 01, 03, 23, 00, 00));
 DateSpan dateRange4 = new DateSpan(new DateTime(2012, 01, 01, 23, 00, 00), new DateTime(2012, 01, 03, 09, 00, 00));
 DateSpan dateRange5 = new DateSpan(new DateTime(2012, 01, 02, 12, 00, 00), new DateTime(2012, 01, 02, 20, 00, 00));
 DateSpan dateRange6 = new DateSpan(new DateTime(2012, 01, 02, 20, 00, 00), new DateTime(2012, 01, 03, 03, 00, 00));
 DateSpan dateRange7 = new DateSpan(new DateTime(2012, 01, 02, 15, 00, 00), new DateTime(2012, 01, 03, 00, 00, 00));

Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("dateRange1: {0} ({1})", dateRange1.GetWorkTimeSpan(workTimeBegin, workTimeEnd), dateRange1.GetWorkTimeSpan(workTimeBegin, workTimeEnd).TotalHours));
Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("dateRange2: {0} ({1})", dateRange2.GetWorkTimeSpan(workTimeBegin, workTimeEnd), dateRange2.GetWorkTimeSpan(workTimeBegin, workTimeEnd).TotalHours));
Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("dateRange3: {0} ({1})", dateRange3.GetWorkTimeSpan(workTimeBegin, workTimeEnd), dateRange3.GetWorkTimeSpan(workTimeBegin, workTimeEnd).TotalHours));
Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("dateRange4: {0} ({1})", dateRange4.GetWorkTimeSpan(workTimeBegin, workTimeEnd), dateRange4.GetWorkTimeSpan(workTimeBegin, workTimeEnd).TotalHours));
Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("dateRange5: {0} ({1})", dateRange5.GetWorkTimeSpan(workTimeBegin, workTimeEnd), dateRange5.GetWorkTimeSpan(workTimeBegin, workTimeEnd).TotalHours));
Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("dateRange6: {0} ({1})", dateRange6.GetWorkTimeSpan(workTimeBegin, workTimeEnd), dateRange6.GetWorkTimeSpan(workTimeBegin, workTimeEnd).TotalHours));
Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("dateRange7: {0} ({1})", dateRange7.GetWorkTimeSpan(workTimeBegin, workTimeEnd), dateRange7.GetWorkTimeSpan(workTimeBegin, workTimeEnd).TotalHours));
```

## Result

```
dateRange1: 1.12:00:00 (36) // correct
dateRange2: 1.18:00:00 (42) // correct
dateRange3: 1.18:00:00 (42) // correct
dateRange4: 19:00:00 (19) // correct
dateRange5: 06:00:00 (6) // correct
dateRange6: 00:00:00 (0) // correct
dateRange7: 03:00:00 (3) // correct
```

Works now as I want it to work... :)